# Symfony DomCrawler How how to click on a link that executes js code

Tags: javascript, laravel, symfony, web-scraping, web-crawler

How can I use a crawler to click on the  link that executes the js code, this link does not have an HREF attribute.
Can a crawler execute js code on a page through a client?

I tried like this but it didn't work

```
        $link = $crawler->filter('#list-65544856 div[class = "DJt7 DJuf"]')->link();
```

Answer (score 0):

to execute JS you must utilize another testing framework.
E.g. https://github.com/symfony/panther